In JS,Want to add event listener when mouse is moved anywhere, and the function is to display/hide content of the page
I want to add an event listener which, when user's mouse moves, will display the contents of the page for x seconds, then goes blank.
my guess will be to use onmousemove and whole page shall be the canvas, but i cant wrap my head around it quite, about the two functions i want to include
Edit 1:


   <script>
        function showText() {
            const element = document.getElementById('infoText');
            element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        document.addEventListener('mousemove',showText);
        setTimeout(function(){
            const element = document.getElementById('infoText');
            element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        },15000);
    </script>
#infoText{
  visibility: hidden;
  }
<body>
    <div id = "infoText" class = "bodyOne">
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
    
    



so this is what i've tried so far,  thanks to @A Haworth and @mykaf and some reading, and it kinda works. When I open the page its blank canvas,with only bg showing. Then when i move the mouse, till timeout the text is visible, then disappears. But when I move the mouse again, text reappears and does not disappear back again.
I tried to put it in a while loop, with defining an incremental variable like I do in C, but its not working.

Try body becoming visibility: hidden, reason for suggesting that is that is won’t move anything

I'd suggest using a css class to hide your page, like @AHaworth suggested with the visibility property. Start with the class set on the element. One function, fired when the mouse moves, would remove the class and call setTimeout(), which then would call another function that adds the class back to the element. But please show what you have tried so far.

The setTimeout needs to be inside the mouse move. And you need to be careful about setting several timeouts as the mouse keeps moving.

ok haworth thanks again,that served the intended purpose, everything is working now. The page only has a paragraph of descriptive text that appears/disappears so mouse movement won't be any  trouble I guess.



   <script>
        function showText() {
            const element = document.getElementById('infoText');
            element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(){
            showText();
        setTimeout(function(){
            const element = document.getElementById('infoText');
            element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        },10000);
    });
   </script>
#infoText{
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Norse Bold';
  color: #cc0000;
  font-size: 30px;

}



so this is one way to do it. We add element visibility property in css and toggle it with event listener, also adding timeout.  I;ve set the timeout to 10seconds(value is written in ms)

This may or may not matter of course, but I wonder whether you have thought through exactly what is happening. When I tried your code I got 421 move events before getting 162 timeout events and so on. Why do you not clear the timeout before creating another one?
